# Why aren't my questions being well-received?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

I've been an active member of the Stack Exchange network for a little under a year now, and I've been trying hard to integrate myself into Arqade. I've played games since I was a kid, and I really like the idea of being able to seek help from other players without having to wade through Reddit or GameFaqs.

At the moment, the questions I've asked on Arqade have not been well received, especially compared to other Exchange sites in which I have considerably less experience. They're not poorly scored, per se, they're just zeroes. Nobody is looking at them, and if they are, they aren't answering them.

I've asked nine questions, and of those, only three of them have received answers from the community. I asked a very firmly answerable question on a newly released AAA game, and I ended up answering it myself a couple days later after I finished the game myself. A question on a fairly well-known free horror game was passed over as well. The latest question I asked sits at -2, I spent nearly fifteen minutes formatting the stupid thing to make sure it's readable and well-researched, and I fundamentally don't understand what's not right with it.

I've got very positive scores on most of the other Stack Exchange sites I visit, so I'm ruling out an understanding of the Stack Exchange system. I've also scoured the help topics, to the point of getting in protracted arguments with other users on topicality of other people's questions, and I can verify that all of my questions are firmly on-topic.

Is there something I'm not understanding about Arqade's purpose or question focus?

EDIT: And, again, I am arguing and justifying the existence of my question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320926/how-do-you-apply-a-vignere-cipher-to-decode-the-have-a-nice-weekend-file). I don't get this, I took deliberate pains to find a popular game, phrase a question to guarantee topicality, and picked a subject that has a very clear and concise problem and solution, and I still have to argue that a gameplay challenge delivered directly to the player is on-topic and manually convince people my problem is worthy of their time. It still feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: The first thing that I see in your profile is that you are asking questions in tags that aren't really all that active. You have 2 questions in "bigger" tags and one of them is a duplicate (they typically don't get too many upvotes). If you are asking questions in a tag with low activity, chances are there aren't a lot of users on the site who are familiar with the game. Personally I tend to ignore games/tags I'm not familiar with since I can't always know whether a question is good or bad.

Comment: See [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12605/145980) for a similar question. There's a lot of factors that go into the votes on a post. Obviously the quality of the question is the biggest factor, but other things (like time of day, popularity of the game, etc) can also increase or decrease the number of views (and subsequently votes) you'll receive.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can evaluate your question's feedback by checking out the number of views. A question with ~30 views (like some of yours) has a much less chance to get answered or voted on than a question with 100s of views or even 1000s, like it can happen with more popular tags. It's a matter of how many people on Arqade are interested in those games/tags.

Only because a game seems to be fairly known it doesn't necessarily mean we have enough people being able to answer questions about it. I have some unanswered questions myself - even for really popular games like FIFA 18. It's not a matter of people hating you or your questions, sometimes they just don't know the answer. In this case it is usually well received when you're finally able to answer your own question after even more research, because it shows extra effort and helps both sides, you and us as the community: We get a good and specific question and a good answer. People will find it, eventually ask more questions, the game tag gets more attention and everybody wins™ (- Frank :P)